# Scraping data from Consumer Affairs Website

Tags: r, text-mining, rvest

I'm trying to download reviews from http://consumeraffairs.com using Rvest. I was able to download the text but I could not get the ratings since it is an image. Is there a way to get the ratings in number? I'm using selectorgadget to get the CSS.

```
comcast <- 
 read_html("https://www.consumeraffairs.com/cable_tv/comcast_cable.html")

rating <- comcast%>%
  html_nodes(".star-rc span") %>%
  html_text()
rating
```

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the source of that URL, you'll see that ratings are stored like this:

```
<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="1">
```

So one way to get a vector with the ratings (for the first page at least):

```
comcast %>% 
  html_nodes("meta[itemprop=ratingValue]") %>% 
  html_attr("content")

 [1] "3" "1" "1" "5" "1" "1" "2" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "1" "1" "2"
[25] "1" "1" "1" "3" "1" "1"
```

Comment: Thanks @nielfws! I was able to extract the ratings but I'm having issues with the consumer increased rating option. I check the source of the URL and some have two "ratingValue" in one reviewer. Is there a way to remove the first one?

Comment: this is the source: <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="2"><meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5"><span class="review__rating-label">Consumer Increased Rating!</span><div class="star-diff positive new-4" data-info-text="Rating changed from 2 to 4"><div class="star-rating-v1 diff three-steps star-sel-4 star-sel-last-3"><div class="star-rc-unselected-container" style="width:60%;"><div class="star-rc-unselected"><span class="change-num">2</span></div><meta content="4.0" itemprop="ratingValue">

Comment: Looks like that's for the case when users change ratings, so you'd want the latest, not the first. You'll have to write some logic to work through those cases.